# GWT: How can I wrap an html icon to a gwt widget?

Tags: html, gwt

I have a HTMLPanel defined by a html string which contains an image and an icon. I need getters for them to add event handlers. There is an Image widget matching with html image. So I can *Image.wrap(Document.get().getElementById("image"));*

I am trying to addClickHandler outside of this Composite. How should I deal with the icon?

```
public class EvtPanel extends Composite{
private HTMLPanel htmlPanel=new HTMLPanel("");

String html="<div class=\"container\">\r\n" + 
        "  <img id=\"image\" src=\"imgUrl\" alt=\"altStr\" class=\"image\">\r\n" + 
        "  <div class=\"overlay\" style=\"text-align: center;\">\r\n" + 
            "  <i id=\"iconBars\" class=\"fa fa-bars\" style=\"font-size:36px;\"></i>\r\n" +
        "  </div>\r\n" + 
        "</div>\r\n" + 
        "";

public EvtPanel(String _imgUrl, String _altStr)
{
    html=html.replace("imgUrl", _imgUrl);
    html=html.replace("altStr", _altStr);
    htmlPanel.getElement().setInnerHTML(html);
    initWidget(htmlPanel);
}

public Image getEvtImage()
{
    Image img=Image.wrap(Document.get().getElementById("image"));
    return img;
}
public Icon getMenu()
{
    //How can I wrap the iconBars to gwt widget?
}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using [GWT-Bootstrap](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap). If that's not the case, let me know.

First, it is a bad habit to use html literals in the code. It is difficult to maintain. You should use uiBinder instead. In uiBinder `ui.xml` file you can use both html and widgets.

`EvtPanel.ui.xml` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
    xmlns:gwtbootstrap3="urn:import:org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui">

    <g:HTMLPanel>
        <div class="container">
            <gwtbootstrap3:Image ui:field="image" />
            <div class="overlay" style="text-align: center;">
                <gwtbootstrap3:Icon ui:field="iconBars" type="BARS" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

---

`EvtPanel.java` file:

```
import org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.Icon;
import org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.Image;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiField;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class EvtPanel extends Composite {

    private static EvtPanelUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(EvtPanelUiBinder.class);

    interface EvtPanelUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, EvtPanel> {}

    @UiField
    Image image;
    @UiField
    Icon iconBars;

    public EvtPanel(String _imgUrl, String _altStr) {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

        image.setUrl(_imgUrl);
        image.setAltText(_altStr);
    }

    public Image getEvtImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public Icon getMenu() {
        return iconBars;
    }
}
```

Notice that in uiBinder file `image` and `iconBars` are declared as widgets from `org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui` package.

Those widgets are then declared in java file using `@UiField` annotation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply very much. I am using Font Awesome Icons. How can I wrap the fa-bars to GWT widget?

Comment: OK, and what is the full package name of the `Icon` in `public Icon getMenu()`?

Comment: I have installed GWTbootstrap3 and it supports Icon widget. But Icon does not support Icon.wrap. How can I turn the fa-bars to Icon widget if I dont use uibinder? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can try to first wrap `overlay` div as a HTMLPanel (`HTMLPanel.wrap(...)`), then create an `Icon` and add it to the `overlay` wrapped panel. Anyway, I strongly recommend using uiBinder.

Comment: BTW: Does your `getEvtImage` method work? Don't you get `"A widget that has an existing parent widget may not be added to the detach list"` error message?

Comment: I need to do it this way because we have a team member responsible for html.

Comment: No, the getEvtImage doesn't work. I think it is about the on Attach problem, since Image.wrap can only work after the attach.

Comment: I do agree with @Adam. You should use UiBinders instead of HTML code as a string. It's not hard to convert HTML code to the UiBinder/GWT code. HTML code is impossible to maintain and UiBinders provide much better reusability.